# Run Time error 4605 on pasting a table into an email

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to paste a table from excel into an email using VBA, however, I am runnning into a

> run time error 4605 : "this method or property is not available
>   because the document is locked for editing".

I am expereining this error on the following line:

```
pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
```

the entire code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Forcast()

Dim Email_week_Row As Long
Dim LastRow_Week As Long
Dim Send_To_Week As String
Dim Send_To_Email_Week As String
Dim Another_Employee_Week As String
Dim Another_Employee_Email_Week As String
Dim Item_No_Week As String
Dim System_No_Week As String
Dim Protocol_No_Week As String
Dim Due_Date_Week As String
Dim Target_Due_Date_Week As String
Dim Task_is_With_Week As String
Dim Status_Week As String
Dim Manager_Email_Week As String
Dim Forcast_Range As Integer
Dim Forcast_Word As String
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim xInspect As Object ' for inputing table into email
Dim pageEditor As Object ' for inputing table into email
Dim Foracst_Range_Date As Date


'Setting the emails to be CC'd

Manager_Email_Week = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email").Range("B37").Value
Another_Employee_Email_Week = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email").Range("B33").Value

'getting the number of items in the sheet

Sheets("Requalifications").Activate
LastRow_Week = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D7:D1001"), "*")

    Sheets("Email").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email").Range("U7:AC9999").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

'Setting the forcast range length and the wording for the email

            Counter = 6 ' setting -1 the first row for the email table

    For Email_week_Row = 7 To (LastRow_Week + 6)

        Foracst_Range_Date = (Date + Forcast_Range)

        If Sheets("Qual").Cells(Email_week_Row, 14).Value <= (Date + 30) And Sheets("Qual").Cells(Email_week_Row, 14).Value > Date Then

        Counter = Counter + 1

            'Add up all the requals due within the forcast range


            Sheets("Email").Cells(Counter, 21).Value = Sheets("Qual").Cells(Email_week_Row, 3).Value
            Sheets("Email").Cells(Counter, 22).Value = Sheets("Qual").Cells(Email_week_Row, 4).Value
            Sheets("Email").Cells(Counter, 23).Value = Sheets("Qual").Cells(Email_week_Row, 5).Value
            Sheets("Email").Cells(Counter, 24).Value = Sheets("Qual").Cells(Email_week_Row, 7).Value
            Sheets("Email").Cells(Counter, 25).Value = Sheets("Qual").Cells(Email_week_Row, 8).Value
            Sheets("Email").Cells(Counter, 26).Value = Sheets("Qual").Cells(Email_week_Row, 11).Value
            Sheets("Email").Cells(Counter, 27).Value = Sheets("Qual").Cells(Email_week_Row, 13).Value
            Sheets("Email").Cells(Counter, 28).Value = Sheets("Qual").Cells(Email_week_Row, 14).Value
            Sheets("Email").Cells(Counter, 29).Value = Sheets("Qual").Cells(Email_week_Row, 15).Value

        End If

    Next Email_week_Row

            Manager_Email_Week = Sheets("Email").Range("B37").Value
            Another_Employee_Email_Week = Sheets("Email").Range("B33").Value

            Dim OutApp As Object
            Dim OutMail As Object

            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

                With OutMail

                    .CC = Manager_Email_Week & "; " & Another_Employee_Email_Week
                    .Subject = "Due: " & Forcast_Word
                    .HTMLBody = "<html><p>Hi, " & "</p>" & _
                    "<p> Here is the next " & Forcast_Word & ":" & "</p>"

                    Set xInspect = OutMail.GetInspector
                    Set pageEditor = xInspect.WordEditor

                    Sheets("Email").Range("Forcast_Table_Email").Copy 'inputting table

                    pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)
                    pageEditor.Application.Selection.End = pageEditor.Application.Selection.Start
                    pageEditor.Application.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)

                    .display
                    '.Send

                    Set pageEditor = Nothing
                    Set xInspect = Nothing

                End With

    MsgBox ("A forcast has been drafted")

        On Error GoTo 0

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
```

I am not familiar ith this error and the microsoft help pages dont really explain what the issue could be specific to this example.

The table is created by extracting the information from one sheet and putting it on another if it is within the correct date range. Column 14 is a column with the list of dates.

Comment: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail4.htm

Comment: I had a look at this but it seems over complicated, with this version it is 3 lines if code, and yes I am aware it is not working presently haha. theorectically though, if both worked then which would run faster?

Comment: I have used it in the past, and it is very simple to use. You dont have to modify it like other codes you "find" online...  and if speed is your concern, i would not worry about that.

Comment: you were right it was quite simple to implement, altough I am still curious to know why the above did not work.

Comment: (Regarding your Raspberry Pi question, I wonder if you could ask that on _Super User_).